# What type to give for java.time.Instant while fetching StructType from case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a case class

```
case class A(tm: java.time.Instant)
```

While trying to get StructType of this case class with

```
ScalaReflection.schemaFor[A].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

I am getting the below error

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error]     at sample.spark.streaming.StructuredStreaming.main(StructuredStreaming.scala)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type java.time.Instant is not supported
```

Could anyone please tell me how do I solve this? I have searched a lot but could not find anything to solve this. And no, I cannot change the type `java.time.Instant` in the case class.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** You simply cannot use `java.time.*` classes as part of a schema (in structured queries / Datasets).

You can however load the dataset as a `DataFrame` and `map` the `java.time.Instant` field to a supported type (i.e. for which an `Encoder` is available).

See [org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits) for the list of available encoders.

---

> And no, I cannot change the type java.time.Instant in the case class.

Well, then you have to create your own case class to use in Spark.